# How to identify an opensea "collection" minted using the opensea contract?

Tags: nft, erc-721, opensea

This is the contract https://polygonscan.com/address/0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963

If you look at the interface https://polygonscan.com/address/0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963#readContract there doesn't seem to be any way to know which collection a token belongs to. There are millions of NFTs in that contract and opensea's website separates them by collection, but how can I do that without using opensea's centralized api?

I don't need to fetch the collection name, just some unique identifier for a collection would work.